# How to continuously pull messages from service bus queue by using spring boot java application

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azureservicebus, azure-queues

How to continuously pull messages from service bus queue. Like in aws we have :

spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging

and a :  [Link](https://www.netsurfingzone.com/aws/spring-boot-aws-sqs-listener-example/#:%7E:text=Create%20Spring%20Boot%20aws%20sqs%20listener%20class.&text=We%20are%20using%20%40SqsListener%20annotation,a%20message%20from%20AWS%20SQS.) to explain more

How to do similar thing in azure?

Answer (score 1):

Same you can do in Azure as well.

You can create queues using the [Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quickstart-portal), [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quickstart-powershell), [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quickstart-cli), or [Resource Manager templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-resource-manager-namespace-queue). Then, send and receive messages using clients written in [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues), [Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-queues), [Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-python-how-to-use-queues), and [JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-nodejs-how-to-use-queues).

***Receive messages from a queue***

> Add a method named receiveMessages to receive messages from the queue.
> This method creates a ServiceBusProcessorClient for the queue by
> specifying a handler for processing messages and another one for
> handling errors. Then, it starts the processor, waits for few seconds,
> prints the messages that are received, and then stops and closes the
> processor

For more information you can refer this ***[MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-queues)*** for Create a console project and Configure your application to use Service Bus